# Display the first page of a PDF file in reduced size (just like the navigation side bar that appears when viewing a PDF file)

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I have a list of file names stored in a database. The list of files is displayed using an HTML template using Flask. The file type is PDF. The file can be viewed using Flask, and the user can view the file in the browser.

The section of code that allows you to view the PDF file completely is as follows:

```
    from flask import send_from_directory

    return send_from_directory(
        directory = 'static/uploads/resultado_de_rx',
        path      = filename,
        mimetype  = 'application/pdf' )
```

When the content of the file is displayed on the screen, the sidebar is displayed on the left side, and the content of the file on the right side. I don't know the correct name of the side bar that is used to scroll through the contents of the file. The screenshot below is a sample of how the file is displayed, with the sidebar on the left side.

[image]

The content of the file in PDF format is an image of an x-ray. And the side navigation bar shows the content of the first page on the left side in a reduced size.

My question is the following: How can I display the first page of the PDF file in a reduced size. I do not want the content of the pdf file to be displayed.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks.